# How do I specify the ODBC Access Driver Format when creating the database

Tags: c#, c++, c, odbc, ms-access-2007

Using C, I am trying to create an Access 2007 database file using ODBC by way of the [SQLConfigDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
char szDriverName[] = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)";
char szAttr[] = "CREATE_DB=c:\access2007.accdb";
SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN, szDriverName, szAttr);
```

I want the file extension of the new database to be .accdb but when I run the code above, I always get c:\access2007.accdb.mdb.  I can specify 12.x (accdb) or 4.x (mdb) from ODBC Admin as in the image below, but how do I do it via ODBC API?

[image: Create Database with ODBC Microsoft Access drivers]

I am able to create the User DSN, however I feel that it is also in the wrong format as I have not tested it.

How do I define the Format Version using ODBC/Access API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CREATE_DBV12:

```
char szDriverName[] = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)";
char szAttr[] = "CREATE_DBV12=c:\access2007.accdb";
SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN, szDriverName, szAttr);
```

Comment: Do you have any source for this information or was it simply a guess?  I searched and searched for this information but never located the 'CREATE_DBV12' property.  Even now that I know this, a google search for 'CREATE_DBV12' returns 0 results.

Comment: I ended up opening the Microsoft Access ODBC dll (ACEODBC.DLL) in notepad and searching through the string constants.  I first searched for the CREATE_DB (they are unicode strings, so I searched for "C R E A") constant and the first thing I hit was CREATE_DBV12, so I tried it and it worked.  There are probably tools that let you browse the string constants, but for me opening the DLL in notepad is not that big of an issue.