# Create Access Database in C# using ODBC

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7-x64

How can I create an MS Access database using C# and ODBC?

Comment: I know this is probably not teh way to go, but have you considered embedding blank Access 2000, 2003, 2007 databases into your assembly, and write them to disk as required? I have used this technique successfully!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this:
[How do I specify the ODBC Access Driver Format when creating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205633/how-do-i-specify-the-odbc-access-driver-format-when-creating-the-database)

I'd say like this:

```
enum RequestFlags : int
{
    ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1,
    ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2,
    ODBC_REMOVE_DSN = 3,
    ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4,
    ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN = 5,
    ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN = 6,
    ODBC_REMOVE_DEFAULT_DSN = 7
}


[DllImport("ODBCCP32.DLL",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool SQLConfigDataSourceW(UInt32 hwndParent , RequestFlags fRequest, string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);
```

Having this in your main method:

```
string strDriverName = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)";
string strAttr = "CREATE_DBV12=c:\access2007.accdb";
SQLConfigDataSource(0, RequestFlags.ODBC_ADD_DSN, strDriverName, strAttr );
```

**Warning: Untested**

Note: I copied the pInvoke info from pinvoke.net.
UInt32 hwndParent seems wrong, that should probably be UIntPtr. 
This is especially important on Win64, which I think you need when I look at your tags.
If so, use UIntPtr.Zero instead of 0. But try first.

Also note that I wouldn't use an access database for new projects if they are intended to be large. If you need a standalone database, use Firebird embedded instead. That way you can save yourself a lot of trouble later.

Also note that newer 64-bit versions of windows ship without Access-driver preinstalled AFAIK.